# Going in production: how to serve my static assets without NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, production-environment

In development I used to have my Node server serve my static files (img, pdf, etc.) but as production is getting closer, I feel it is very inefficient and puts an unneeded load on Node.
What is the right way to have my assets served by a different server? Is there a ready-made solution? Should I use a "good old" Apache-PHP stack? What should I know about ports forwarding and stuff like that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Google [Node.js + Nginx](https://www.google.ru/search?q=node.js+%2B+nginx).

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/nnnnathann/3491640) that shows an example of using Apache as a reverse proxy with node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this done several ways.

1. Use [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main) to serve the static assets. Faster than Apache for static assets.
2. Use [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) to serve static assets. You'll upload your assets to S3 and enable Cloudfront to be a CDN.
3. Use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), I'm less experienced with this method so can't tell you much accept they handle CDN and I believe some caching.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll look into each of those. What's your personal favorite?

Comment: If you're willing to run your own server then probably Nginx. If not then I'm a fan of S3 and Cloudfront.